# Relación 1 a 0 en un Modelo ER en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql, modelorelacional

Tengo una base de datos creada en SQL Server con las siguientes tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE T_BASE_DASHBOARD(
    id INT IDENTITY (1,1),
    llave VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PP INT NOT NULL,
    CD VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    PAIS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_llave PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id)
);

CREATE TABLE T_ARIMA(
    llave VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PAIS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    FECHA DATE NOT NULL,
    PP INT NOT NULL,
    CD VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    ARIMA FLOAT,
CONSTRAINT PK_arima PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (llave)
);

CREATE TABLE T_FP(
    llave VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PAIS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    FECHA DATE NOT NULL,
    PP INT NOT NULL,
    CD VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    FP FLOAT,
CONSTRAINT PK_FP PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (llave)
);

CREATE TABLE T_LAG2(
    llave VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PAIS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    FECHA DATE NOT NULL,
    PP INT NOT NULL,
    CD VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    LAG2 FLOAT,
CONSTRAINT PK_LAG2 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (llave)
);

ALTER TABLE T_BASE_DASHBOARD ADD CONSTRAINT FK_dashboard_arima FOREIGN KEY (llave)
REFERENCES T_ARIMA(llave);

ALTER TABLE T_BASE_DASHBOARD ADD CONSTRAINT FK_dashboard_fp FOREIGN KEY (llave)
REFERENCES T_FP(llave);

ALTER TABLE T_BASE_DASHBOARD ADD CONSTRAINT FK_dashboard_lag2 FOREIGN KEY (llave)
REFERENCES T_LAG2(llave);
```

Lo que primero hago, es llenar de información las tablas T_ARIMA, T_FP y T_LAG2. Luego trato de llenar la de T_BASE_DASHBOARD pero me marca un error

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dashboard_arima". The conflict occurred in database "DB_ESTRUCTURA", table "dbo.T_ARIMA", column 'llave'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Considero que es porque un registro que trato de meter a la tabla T_BASE_DASHBOARD existe en T_FP y T_LAG2 pero no en T_ARIMA.

No se como darle una solución debido a que así es le funcionamiento, algunos registros pueden no existir en alguna tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Si cambias la definición de la tabla T_BASE_DASHBOARD puedes hacerlo, insertando un valor null, para la columna llave, que es la foreign key de las otras tres tablas.

El único cambio, es quitar la restricción de NOT NULL de la columna llave por NULL.

```
DROP TABLE T_BASE_DASHBOARD;
CREATE TABLE T_BASE_DASHBOARD(
    id INT IDENTITY (1,1),
    llave VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    PP INT NOT NULL,
    CD VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    PAIS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_llave PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id)
);

ALTER TABLE T_BASE_DASHBOARD ADD CONSTRAINT FK_dashboard_arima FOREIGN KEY (llave)
REFERENCES T_ARIMA(llave);

ALTER TABLE T_BASE_DASHBOARD ADD CONSTRAINT FK_dashboard_fp FOREIGN KEY (llave)
REFERENCES T_FP(llave);

ALTER TABLE T_BASE_DASHBOARD ADD CONSTRAINT FK_dashboard_lag2 FOREIGN KEY (llave)
REFERENCES T_LAG2(llave);

INSERT INTO T_BASE_DASHBOARD ( llave,PP,CD, PAIS)
VALUES (null, 1,'b','c');

(1 fila afectada)
```